# grand central dispatch, operation queues, async, view will and did disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

Hopefully these questions will seem helpful to people out there.  I've been learning objective c, [mostly from this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449372422), which I found to be amazing and helpful even for a noob.  My questions all have to deal with this:

What happens to the queue when the user changes the view?  I can't seem to find a good explanation anywhere.

From my understanding, using the NSOperation and its queue, you can always cancel it using the "cancel"...but what if you don't want it to cancel?  What if, say a user selects multiple images to upload to the server, and you create a queue with the order, and the user switches to a new view controller?  This might be time consuming, especially on a slow mobile network.  I remember reading somewhere that iOS gives around 20 seconds extra time for a method to finish its work, but I think that's only when the app enters to the background.

For the GCD, there is no cancel method...so what happens in the background if you use async?  I guess if you don't have a response to the queue, I mean you don't update the UI in any way, shouldn't the queue finish since it's sent to another thread?

I'm sure there is much more that I don't understand as far as threading goes, but I hope I made my question clear.  And please please don't tell me to use the AFNetworking stuff...I tried using all those keychain wrappers out there and it all failed.  Thanks to the book, the straight Apple code from the book did everything easily.  I would rather learn the basics first before using the easier way out.

I would really appreciate if someone took the time to talk about this.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern about only having a set amount of time to finish tasks only applies to when you switch away from your app to another app. And in that case you can use the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method so your app can request time to finish those tasks if your app happens to go into background. See the *Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background* section of the [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28) section of the *iOS App Programming Guide* for more information.

But if you're still within your app (whether you transitioned to another view controller or not), anything you've added to your operation queue will continue to run until you cancel those operations (or the app is suspended or terminated). Likewise, anything you've added to a GCD queues will continue to run until the app is suspended or terminated.

In both of these scenarios, the above `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` will give you a few minutes to finish your queued tasks/operations after your app goes into the background.

Comment: Ok, that's great to know!  Thanks for the link too.  One more question, which is better to use?  Right now I'm very comfortable with GCD because it's so straight forward with switching to the main thread and grouping tasks.  Is it just a personal preference?

Comment: @denikov GCD is fine for one-off tasks. You generally use operation queues if you have many operations and want to constrain how many can run concurrently (with `maxConcurrentOperationCount`) or if you need fine grained control over the dependencies between operations. BTW, operation queues are, in their simplest form, not much harder than GCD dispatch queues (e.g. instead of `dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{...})` you'd do `[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{...}]`. GCD, though, is invaluable for lower-level tasks, like synchronizing access to objects, timers, semaphores, etc.

Comment: Personally, I use GCD for those lower level tasks, but use operation queues for app-level tasks (e.g. network requests, image processing, etc.).

Comment: Thanks again for that.  Marked your answer, but another question, hopefully last one :)  Lower-level tasks...should I not use GCD for working with the server (getting data, uploading stuff)?

Comment: Ok, you beat me to it...that was my next question.  Thanks, I'll just into operations then.  And the reason being is you have more control with operations, right?  That being the main one?

Comment: @denikov Yep, with network requests, iOS can only do 4-5 at a time anyway, so if you use GCD with many network requests, you risk having the latter network requests time-out on slow network connections. By using operation queue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of, say, 4, that tells your app to not even try a network request until you're confident it can start without risking timeout. Bottom line, operation queues are invaluable if issuing many network requests. If only doing one request, though, it doesn't matter nearly as much.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help and thorough explanation.  Back to work!